# Combine string without delimiter when variable is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine strings into a single line on a spreadsheet. I am using a comma as my delimiter. How can I have it so if a variable is blank not to use the delimiter. Here is the code I have

```
 Concat = Join(Array(var1, var2, var3,` var4, var5), " ,")
 ws.Range("CU" & i).Value2 = Concat
```

And here is sample of the results returned.

```
, , , ,
 , ,Eligibility date , ,
```

I have var1, var2, var3.....

I am wondering how I get rid of the commas and blank spaces if var1 = blank, var2 = blank etc.

Comment: You could do For/Each logic instead of `Join` function. Also, it's "delimiter" not "deliminator" :)

Comment: What are your desired results?

Comment: Thanks. I would like it to read "Eligibility date" for the second entry

Comment: Also, you're currently using a *space + comma* as your delimiter. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only 5 variables, you could easily brute-force it:

```
Sub test()
Dim concat$, delimit$
Dim v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, val
v1 = ""
v2 = "adfadf"
v3 = "Eligibility"
v4 = ""
v5 = "floerg"

delimit = " ,"

For Each val in Array(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
    If val <> "" Then
        c = c & delimit & val
    End If
Next
c = Right(c, Len(c) - Len(delimit))
Debug.Print c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I modified your code a bit and arrived at a solution. The v1 - v5 are "answered" within a loop.

```
   Dim v1 As String, v2 As String, v3 As String, v4 As String, v5 As String, delimit As String
        Dim val As Variant
        x = ""
        v1 = ""
        v2 = ""
        v3 = ""
        v4 = ""
        v5 = ""
        delimit = ","

For Each val In Array(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
        If val <> "" Then
            x = x & delimit & val
        End If
    Next

    If x <> "" Then
        x = Right(x, Len(x) - Len(delimit))
        ws.Range("CU" & i).Value2 = x
    End If
```